# Calculating conditional probabilities

Tags: statistics

A question in one of my texts starts as thus:

$X$~$Unif(-1,+1)$, $Z$ ~ $Unif(0,0.1)$. $X,Z$ independent. Define $Y=X^2 + Z$.

Then, $Y|X$~$Unif(x^2,x^2+0.1)$

I don't understand how the pdf of Y|X was drawn so quickly. Is there an easy way of doing this, or something trivial I'm missing here? The only way I have been taught to calculate conditional probabilities is by using:

$$\frac{f_{x,y}(x,y)}{f_{x}(x)}$$

... but the question uses the conditional to calculate the joint distribution.

Comment: @Did Edited and removed the link. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Answer (score 0):

For every $x$ in $(-1,+1)$, conditionally on $X=x$, $Y=x^2+Z$, $Z$ is independent of $X$, and the distribution of $x^2+Z$ is uniform on $(x^2,x^2+0.1)$. This pretty much summarizes the intuition. A rigorous derivation would yield the same result.

More generally, if $X$ and $Z$ are independent, then for every $x$,  conditionally on $X=x$, $Y=G(X,Z)$ follows the distribution of $G(x,Z)$.